# Getting the same picture onItemClick in GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

When i start up the app it loads all the movie posters correctly. When i click on a poster it should start DetailActivity and display the poster i selected. However every poster i click all displays the same one.

**MainActivityFragment**

```
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
    private static final int MOVIE_LOADER = 0;

    private final String LOG_TAG = MainActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String[] MOVIE_COLUMNS = {
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + MovieContract.MovieEntry._ID,
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_POSTER
    };

    static final int COL_MOVIE_ID = 0;
    static final int COL_MOVIE_URL = 1;

    private MovieAdapter mMovieAdapter;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(),null,0);

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movieposter_image_gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l){
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if(cursor != null){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class)
                        .setData(MovieContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivity(intent);
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "Selected item position " + position + ", with id: " + l);
                }
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(MOVIE_LOADER, null, this);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void updateApplication() {

        FetchMovieTask movieTask = new FetchMovieTask(getActivity());
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String sortBy = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_sort_by_key),
                getString(R.string.pref_popular_default));
        movieTask.execute(sortBy);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        updateApplication();

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle){
        Uri movieUri = MovieContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_URI;

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
        movieUri,
        MOVIE_COLUMNS,
        null,
        null,
        null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor){
        mMovieAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader){
        mMovieAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

**DetailActivity**

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new DetailFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class DetailFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

        private final String LOG_TAG = DetailFragment.class.getSimpleName();
        private static final String Movie_SHARE_HASHTAG = " #MovieApp";

        private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
        private String mMovie;
        ImageView poster;



        private static final int DETAIL_LOADER = 0;

        private final String[] DETAIL_COLUMNS = {
                MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + MovieContract.MovieEntry._ID,
                MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_POSTER
        };

        private static final int COL_MOVIE_ID = 0;
        private static final int COL_MOVIE_POSTER = 1;

        public DetailFragment() {
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(DETAIL_LOADER, null, this);
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "In onCreateLoader");
            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            if (intent == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return new CursorLoader(
                    getActivity(),
                    intent.getData(),
                    DETAIL_COLUMNS,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {


            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "In onLoadFinished");
            if (!data.moveToFirst()) {
                return;
            }

            String posterURL = data.getString(COL_MOVIE_POSTER);

            final String POSTERIMAGE_BASE_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/";
            final String POSTERIMAGE_SIZE = "w500";



            poster = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailActivity_image_view);
            final String POSTERIMAGE_URL = POSTERIMAGE_BASE_URL + POSTERIMAGE_SIZE + posterURL;


            Picasso.with(this.getActivity()).load(POSTERIMAGE_URL).into(poster);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Poster Urls: " + POSTERIMAGE_URL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        }

    }

}
```

**MovieAdapter**

```
public class MovieAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private final String LOG_TAG = MovieAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public MovieAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags){
        super(context,c,flags);
    }

    private String convertCursorRowToUXFormat(Cursor cursor){
        String poster = cursor.getString(MainActivityFragment.COL_MOVIE_URL);
        return poster;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context,Cursor cursor,ViewGroup parent){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.poster_image, parent, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        final String POSTERIMAGE_BASE_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/";
        final String POSTERIMAGE_SIZE = "w500";

        ImageView posterImage = (ImageView)view;
        final String POSTERIMAGE_URL = POSTERIMAGE_BASE_URL + POSTERIMAGE_SIZE + convertCursorRowToUXFormat(cursor);

        Picasso.with(context).load(POSTERIMAGE_URL).into(posterImage);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Poster Urls: " + POSTERIMAGE_URL);

    }
}
```

**FetchMovieTask**

```
public class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchMovieTask.class.getSimpleName();


    private final Context mContext;

    public FetchMovieTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    private boolean DEBUG = true;

    private void getMovieDataJSON(String movieJSONStr)
            throws JSONException {

        final String MDB_RESULT = "results";
        final String MDB_POSTER = "poster_path";
        final String MDB_MOVIE_TITLE = "original_title";
        final String MDB_MOVIE_PLOT = "overview";
        final String MDB_MOVIE_RATING = "popularity";
        final String MDB_RELEASE_DATE = "release_date";

        try {
            JSONObject movieJSON = new JSONObject(movieJSONStr);
            JSONArray movieArray = movieJSON.getJSONArray(MDB_RESULT);

            Vector<ContentValues> cVVector = new Vector<>(movieArray.length());

            for (int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++) {
                String poster;
                String title;
                String plot;
                String rating;
                String releaseDate;


                //Get theJSON object representing the movie
                JSONObject movieDetail = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);

                poster = movieDetail.getString(MDB_POSTER);
                title = movieDetail.getString(MDB_MOVIE_TITLE);
                plot = movieDetail.getString(MDB_MOVIE_PLOT);
                rating = movieDetail.getString(MDB_MOVIE_RATING);
                releaseDate = movieDetail.getString(MDB_RELEASE_DATE);

                ContentValues movieDetailValues = new ContentValues();
                movieDetailValues.put(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_NAME, title);
                movieDetailValues.put(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_POSTER, poster);
                movieDetailValues.put(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_PLOT, plot);
                movieDetailValues.put(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_RATING, rating);
                movieDetailValues.put(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_REDATE, releaseDate);

                cVVector.add(movieDetailValues);
            }
            int inserted = 0;

            if (cVVector.size() > 0) {
                ContentValues[] cvArray = new ContentValues[cVVector.size()];
                cVVector.toArray(cvArray);

                inserted = mContext.getContentResolver().bulkInsert(MovieContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_URI, cvArray);
            }

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FetchMovieTask Complete. " + inserted + " Inserted");



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground (String...params){

            if (params.length == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            String movieJSONStr = null;

            try {

                final String MOVIE_BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie";

                Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(MOVIE_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendPath(params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter("api_key", BuildConfig.MOVIE_API_KEY)
                        .build();

                URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built URI " + builtUri.toString());

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                if (inputStream == null) {
                    return null;
                }



  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            movieJSONStr = buffer.toString();
            getMovieDataJSON(movieJSONStr);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
        }
            catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see where you are retrieving the data from the intent in the detail activity. And I'm kind of confused as to how you are setting the data into the intent in the `MainActivity`.

Comment: Sorry about that i just added my fetchmovietask code if that'll help any confusion.

Comment: No. That doesn't help. Are you retrieving any data from the intent in the `DetailActivity`? And highlight the line where you are setting the data to the intent in your `MainActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update variable `COL_MOVIE_POSTER` in `DetailActivity` according to item clicked in gridview of `MainActivityFragment`.

Comment: Shouldn't it have been updated with the onCreateLoader in the DetailActivity.class?